# per Microsoft, ... -- meaning of "per"?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Example:

> VBA has a few module-level utility statements, known as options, that are used for naming
>   conventions, string comparisons, and other internal settings. First off, you may have already
>   noticed the Option Compare Database statement located in the general declarations area of
>   the VBE Code window.
>   **Per Microsoft**, the Option Compare Database statement “performs string comparisons based on
>   the sort order determined by the locale ID of the database where the string comparisons
>   occur.” This statement can be modified to either Option Compare Binary or Option Compare
>   Text instead of Option Compare Database. If your VBE code module does not include an Option
>   Compare statement, VBA will default to Option Compare Binary, which results in string comparisons based on a character’s internal binary representation.

How should I understand **per** used in this type of context? And what does **per Microsoft** exactly mean?

Comment: I believe they meant to say: As per Microsoft's Option Compare Database statement: _"performs string ..."_  You can only use **per** on its own when it's followed by a countable thing: per hour, per day, per house, etc.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/54864/11482

Comment: @Joe Dark: They're quoting from Microsoft documentation. So it's not per the program-language *statement*.

Comment: Search for "define per" : prep. According to; by: _Changes were made to the manuscript per the author's instructions._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**"according to"**

"*According to* Microsoft, the Option Compare Database statement..." does all that technical stuff I don't understand. XD

Other examples:

- Per the First Amendment, we have the right to say what we want.
- Per my mother, I'm the smartest boy in the world.
- Per my father, my brother-in-law is a lazy oaf.

From [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/per):

> 1:  by the means or agency of :  through
>
> 2:  with respect to every member of a specified group :  for each
>
> 3:  according to —often used with as

Comment: It is worth mentioning that "per" in this sense is **often** used with as, for example "as per instructions", "as per usual",etc.

Comment: This answer could be further improved with a reference for your definition.

Answer (score 4):

I agree basically with miltonaut. "Per X" means "as X stated (i.e. said|set forth in writing)". In technical manuals, "in its documentation" is usually implied.

> According to Microsoft's documentation, the Option Compare Database
>   statement “performs string comparisons based on the sort order
>   determined by the locale ID of the database where the string
>   comparisons occur".

Comment: Downvotes should be explained. I'd like to know what it is about the answer above that is found wanting.