# Is the usage of 'per' in the following sentence correct?

Tags: word-usage

> Per research collected by Northern Illinois University, lifelong bilingualism can deter the effects of natural aging. ([source](https://thegoodtrade.com/features/how-to-learn-a-new-language))

I read this in a blog and was confused by the usage of "per" in this sentence. I looked it up in the dictionary and only found that "as per" means "in accordance with". I think the author here is trying to use "per" to mean "according to", but is that correct? I've never seen anything like this before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [per Microsoft, ... -- meaning of "per"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41385/per-microsoft-meaning-of-per)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your analysis.  This *should* be "As per..."  Using "per" as in that article is not in accordance with established use. Using "per" or "as per" seems unnecessary in that context, but I think the author was trying to avoid repeating "According to" from the previous sentence.

However, it is quite clear what the author means. He means "According to".

Comment: I see "per ..." used as short for "as per" all the time. I myself also use it fairly frequently.

Comment: Yeah, I think "as per" would sound odd used instead of "per" - it's very rarely used to start a sentence. Of course you could use "according to", "following from", "looking at", etc, but "per" has a slightly different implication, that what is being said comes entirely and only from the named source, rather than using the source as support; it also doesn't necessarily indicate that the speaker believes the source. "By" is another, maybe more old-fashioned alternative.